# Description field is coming as [ARRAY] instead of the actual array([1,2,3]) in dynamodb when I try to get data using query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, backend, dynamodb-queries

```
Items: [
    {
      Continent: 'Continent#Antarctica',
      SKCountry: 'Country#Chile',
      CreatedAt: 1668579154424,
      description: [Array],
      PKContinent: 'PKContinent',
      id: 16,
      UpdatedAt: 1668579154424
    },
    {
      Continent: 'Continent#Antarctica',
      SKCountry: 'Country#France',
      CreatedAt: 1668579154424,
      description: [Array],
      PKContinent: 'PKContinent',
      id: 15,
      UpdatedAt: 1668579154424
    }]
```

, this is what I am getting but instead of "description: [Array],", I want this, description: [value1, value2, value3]. Also, I am getting this data in console but in browser I am getting an error in console (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tagName')).

this is the code snippet in getAllItems.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    region: "local",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
var table = "Tourism";
const getAllItems = async ()=> {
        var PKContinent = "PKContinent";
        //console.log("check",PKContinent)
        const params = {
            TableName: table,
            KeyConditionExpression: "PKContinent = :pkUpdate AND begins_with(SKCountry, :SKCountry)",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":pkUpdate": PKContinent,
                ":SKCountry": "Country#"
            }
        }
        docClient.query(params, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                var viewArray = [];
                if (data.Items.length === 0) {
                    console.log("data doesn't exists.")
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        })
   
}

module.exports = {
    docClient,
    getAllItems
};
```

this is the code in getAll

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { getAllItems} = require('../getAllItems');

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const getData = await getAllItems();
        res.json(getData);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ err: 'Something went wrong with get' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I believe the issue is when saving the data, not reading it.

You mention you cannot read the data in tbe console? Can you share a screenshot of how that looks in your question.

And can you also share the output of the console which you stated worked, I'll be able to guide you to the issue then.